# json response is interpreted as text/plain

Tags: restkit

I have the following code:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"some-address"]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

RKObjectRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:[self.objectManager responseDescriptors]];

[requestOperation start];
[requestOperation waitUntilFinished];
```

I get the following error.

```
Object request failed: Underlying HTTP request operation failed with error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json"
)}, got text/plain" UserInfo=0x1f5e3c40 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion={"total_rows":16,"offset":1,"rows":[

{"id":"1","key":1,"value":{"_id":"1","_rev":"1-e75042683867a7030fc4d3aa3b72ef35",
"user":{
"userId":"1",
"name":"A",
.......
]}}, .....
```

Why I get this error, when the response is in Json format?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

we did it. just set

```
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKXMLReaderSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"text/plain"];
```

and feel free to change RKXMLReaderSerialization class with RKNSJSONSerialization class if you're using JSON instead of XML (XML was our case).

Comment: The solution works like a charm. Thank you very much. You save my time a lot.

Comment: This worked for me as well. For my use case in the setCompletionBlockWithSuccess I just checked result for nil and handled as I needed. Great tip.

Comment: Should use this line to add to pod file \n
pod 'RKXMLReaderSerialization', :git => 'https://github.com/RestKit/RKXMLReaderSerialization.git', :branch => 'master'

Comment: Yes, but only if you need to parse an XML.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set the mime-type header properly in your response. Note the error says `got text/plain`, while the code is expecting either `application/json` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: what if MIME TYPE (server side) is not under my control? I'm using Restkit 0.20

Comment: then see if you can override/add the client-side acceptable mime-types

Comment: already done. I've used this :

[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKXMLReaderSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"text/plain"];
but it keeps on failing object mapping. Every network request/response works fine in all my app except this one. We've notified "server guys" about this bug (there's no reason to set a text/plain mimetype when you're actually sending a real, well formatted XML) but they won't fix it.

There must be something inside the XML Parser (which is NOT Restkit's anymore since 0.20), maybe I should open another topic for this (nru asked about JSON)